# Removing the DIV that wraps Custom Menu (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom menu that I'm using as a sidebar in my Wordpress site. Inside my functions.php file I registered the menu(s)

```
// Register sub menus
function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
    array(
            'who-we-are' => __( 'Who We Are' ),
            'mission-grantees' => __( 'Mission & Grantees' )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
```

To display the menu I'm using this code:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'menu' => 'mission-grantees' ) ); ?>
```

The issue is that the menu has a DIV and a UL wrapping the list items. Is there a way to remove them?

Thanks.

Comment: But menu will break if you remove that. What problem you are facing now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the `wp_nav_menu()` function, you'll see it uses the following defaults ( among others ):

```
'container' => 'div',
'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
```

You'll need to provide your own to override them.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array(
    'menu' => 'mission-grantees',
    'container' => '',
    'items_wrap' => '%3$s'
) ); ?>
```

Note that since a menu has `<li>` elements, you should put your own list wrapping tags around it.

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you! I have this menu called 'Main Menu' which was the first menu I created. I don't have it registered but using this code `<?php $args = array( 'menu' => 'mainnav', 'container' => false, 'menu_id' => false, 'menu_class' => 'clearfix main-nav'); wp_nav_menu($args); ?>` it shows it as my main menu. That's not a problem I'm just wondering why that is.

Comment: If a matching menu can't be found ( 'mainnav' ), the function SHOULD use ( haven't tested ) the first found non-empty menu as fallback. If you don't want to show that menu, remove that code.